# Authorization Error, 'RoleEntity is not part of the model for the current context'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, owin, roles, asp.net-identity-2

I currently upgrade my code from ASP NET MVC 4 to 5. I had a problem after add OWIN security, below is the code that I use.

```
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public async Task<string> test()
    {
        var role = "";
        using (
        var userManager =
            new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
            var rolesForUser = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            return "test " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + " " + rolesForUser.ElementAt(0);

        }

    }
```

its alway give me error

> The entity type RoleEntity is not part of the model for the current context.

It work normally when I use `[Authorize(Users="username")]`, it only error when I change the 'Users' into 'Roles'. My database is SQLServer and using Entity Framework 5.

Answer (score 0):

i found how to resolve my own issue,

> by default **[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]** is referenced to **System.Web.Mvc**, it should be referenced to **System.Web.Http**

so i change the code to **[System.Web.Http.Authorize(Roles="Admin")]**

i hope it can help some people who have same problem as me.